# Loop with linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have two folders with its respective fields. For example:

```
/1 
/1/image104_1.tif
/1/image136_2.tif

/2
/2/image104_2.tif
/2/image136_2.tif
```

I have listed the folders and its files with the following command:

```
ls -R /test*/ >> /test/output.txt
```

What I need is to merge one image with the one from the other folder automatically. I'm trying to do it as the following but it doesn't work.

```
while read output.txt
do
    echo item: $i (it's not the operation)
done
```

Could you help me, please? Any suggestion would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use parameter expansion in bash:

```
for file in 1/*.tif ; do
    do-your-processing-on "$file" 2/"${file#1/}"
done
```

`#` means "remove the pattern from the left".

Answer (score 0):

```
while read i; do echo item: $i ; done < output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have  to set this in the beginning

```
IFS=$'\n';
```